# Ubuntu Server 19.10 i386 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: server, 19.10, 32-bit, raspberrypi

I want to know if it's possible to install Ubuntu 19.10 Server (i386), for Raspberry Pi, on an older Laptop that only have 32bit architecture?

I wonder if this can be possible, because this version is a i386 based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ubuntu server for the Raspberry pi is designed for an arm processor and will not work on an i386 laptop.

Debian still offers server or desktop for i386 machines.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. I found a better solution for the netbook that i'm trying to "revive", install Voyager 10 (based on debian).